# Get file names in a commit in azure devops using rest api c#

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-sdk-.net, azure-rest-api

I am trying to get the list of files that changed in a commit in AzureDevOps. Is there an api to get this information ?

I am using this but not able to get the information for files.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/attachments/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

```
var attachment = buildClient.GetAttachmentsAsync(projectName, buildRunId, commititem.Type).Result;
```

The above code returns empty value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an api to get this information ?

Yes. You can get the file names in a commit with this API: [Commits - Get Changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get-changes?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits/{commitId}/changes?api-version=6.0
```

For .net sdk, you can refer to this class: [GitCommitChanges Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.sourcecontrol.webapi.gitcommitchanges?view=azure-devops-dotnet)